# Remove a <script> tag in the <head> of all Drupal 7 pages

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, drupal-7

I inherited a Drupal 7 site that uses the Bootstrap 2.3.2 javascript via their CDN:

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I want to use my own JS, and I can't figure out how to remove the above link from my pages. It's not in the theme's .info file. It's not in html.tpl.php. It's not being called by a pre-process function.

Where else should I look?

Comment: Heres a couple of other posts wanting to do a similar thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902456/drupal-unset-javascript-from-header    http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97042/how-do-i-remove-js-from-a-specified-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the cdn version of js, you need to log in as the drupaladmin/superadmin. Than go to Appearance > settings > your theme

In bootstrap settings go to Advance tab, expand BOOTSTRAPCDN. You can see BootstrapCDN version as a select box. You need to select option "Disabled" than save.